# Can't get length of json javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have this code:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'carrinho/fretecheckout/',
        data: {cep: cep, peso: peso, valor: valor, dimensoes: dimensoes, ids: ids},
        dataType : 'json',
        complete: function() {
            $('#checkoutBody').removeClass("loadingfrete");
        },
        success: function(data) {                
            $('#carrinhocep').val(cep);
            var frete = data;
            $('.segundopassofrete').html('');
            $('#freteselecionado').remove();
            for (var i = 0; i < frete['frete'].length; i++) {
```

This code return to me it(localhost):

```
{"frete":[{"peso":"49300","classificador":"Retira","fk_frete":"15","prazo":"Prazo de entrega at\u00e9 2 dias","fk_classificador":"445","fator_cubagem":"4800","peso_real":"1","peso_cubado":"0","fk_fre_peso":"0","fk_fichario":"61440","transportadora":"N","preco_min":"0.00","gratis":"0","gratis_produtos":null,"exibir_estados":"0","imagem":null,"preco":"0.001","valor":"0.001"},{"peso":"49300","classificador":"Moto boy","fk_frete":"17","prazo":"Prazo de entrega 1 dia","fk_classificador":"151","fator_cubagem":"4800","peso_real":"1","peso_cubado":"0","fk_fre_peso":"0","fk_fichario":"60646","transportadora":"N","preco_min":"0.00","gratis":"0","gratis_produtos":null,"exibir_estados":"0","imagem":null,"preco":0.0319249,"valor":0.0319249},{"fk_frete":"27","classificador":"Trans. Jamef","prazo":"De 5 a 10 dias ap\u00f3s o envio","valor":223.54,"transportadora":null,"fk_classificador":null},{"peso":289260,"classificador":"Transportadora","fk_frete":"28","prazo":"Prazo de entrega 10 dias","fk_classificador":"405","fator_cubagem":"3333","peso_real":"1","peso_cubado":"1","fk_fre_peso":"0","fk_fichario":"56080","transportadora":"Y","preco_min":"0.00","gratis":"0","gratis_produtos":null,"exibir_estados":"0","imagem":null,"preco":0,"kiloadd":"1.000","valor":10.61}],"cidade":{"cidade":{"id":"6268","nome":"Londrina"},"estado":{"id":"17","nome":"Paran\u00e1","uf":"PR"}}}
```

And here is the response of the server:

```
{"frete":[{"peso":"4000","classificador":"taxi","fk_frete":"5","prazo":"Prazo de entrega 10 dias","fk_classificador":"357","fator_cubagem":"4800","peso_real":"1","peso_cubado":"0","fk_fre_peso":"0","fk_fichario":"207","transportadora":"N","preco_min":"100.00","gratis":"0","gratis_produtos":null,"exibir_estados":"0","imagem":null,"preco":"11.000","valor":"11.000"},{"peso":10450,"classificador":"Trans. Braspress","fk_frete":"6","prazo":"Prazo de entrega 10 dias","fk_classificador":"837","fator_cubagem":"3333","peso_real":"1","peso_cubado":"1","fk_fre_peso":"0","fk_fichario":"773","transportadora":"Y","preco_min":"0.00","gratis":"0","gratis_produtos":null,"exibir_estados":"0","imagem":null,"preco":"3050.000","valor":"3050.000"},{"peso":7260,"classificador":"BYH","fk_frete":"9","prazo":"Prazo de entrega entre 15 a 35 dias \u00fateis","fk_classificador":"1760","fator_cubagem":"4800","peso_real":"1","peso_cubado":"1","fk_fre_peso":null,"fk_fichario":"786","transportadora":"N","preco_min":null,"gratis":"0","gratis_produtos":null,"exibir_estados":"0","imagem":null,"preco":"0.001","valor":"0.001"},{"valor":46.03,"prazo":"At\u00e9 8 dias ap\u00f3s o envio","cod":"41106","transportadora":"N","fk_frete":"1","classificador":"PAC"},{"valor":49.73,"prazo":"At\u00e9 7 dias ap\u00f3s o envio","cod":"40010","transportadora":"N","fk_frete":"2","classificador":"sedex"}],"cidade":{"cidade":{"id":"5895","nome":"Camb\u00e9"},"estado":{"id":"17","nome":"Paran\u00e1","uf":"PR"}}}
```

Until here everything is OK.

So:

I need to iterate this object and for each "frete" do something. Everything was working fine until 10 minutes ago.

Now I'm trying to test something else, and this code just stopped working without any change.

I debug the code and what I got was:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < frete['frete'].length; i++) {
```

It just doesn't enter the loop. When I check if `frete['frete'].length` has something, I get "Undefined".

So `frete.frete.length` undefined too, and `frete.length` is undefined, I've tried everything you can imagine, and it just doesn't work.

If I check frete, I get `[Object object]` so probably it is an issue in JSON.

The strangest thing of all is, on my localhost it works, on my partner's computer with Chrome it works just fine, and for my partner, it doesn't work with Firefox. On my computer, it doesn't work on both, but on localhost it works fine.
I got some screen shots to explain better:

Working on localhost: [locahost](http://prntscr.com/1mzwgc)

Doesn't working on product: [production](http://prntscr.com/1mzw4w)

Check the firebug in action: [firebug](http://postimg.org/image/mxt2gm0hp/)

Can someone give me some idea?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Most likely the server is all of a sudden not returning anything in the array.

Comment: Go to your developer console and check your network tab. Look at the request for this json and look what exactly it returns. Is it still valid json?

Comment: In the title and sometimes in your question, you have "length" spelled "lenght". Double check that in your code.

Comment: @KevinB on firebug i can get the ajax return and yes it returning like i post

Comment: @CrazyTrain yes i hate this word i aways spell it wrong, but on code i have autocompletion to this =]] i'm pretty sure its right

Comment: As @CrazyTrain said check you speeling cause your code is fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ymfAX/

Comment: Is your loop is inside success function? It seems to be a scope issue.

Comment: What code do you have between `var frete = data;` and `for(...)` ? Add a `console.log(frete)` right before your loop to see if your object hasn't been altered.

Comment: @LeGEC i've edited it with full code

Comment: @CrazyTrain check news ps pls

Comment: According to your last screenshot, `frete.frete` is a plain object, not an Array, so it has no `.length`. Seems like the server has changed the structure.

Comment: @CrazyTrain its a JSON object, and aways be and i aways get length of it and on my localhost still geting, just on production doesn't work =[ its sad

Comment: yes but look at the difference in the format. can you give us the server formatted output to test with please

Comment: @Guerra: JSON data has object and array style structures. I'm just telling you what I see in the screenshot you provided. If you change to `for (var p in frete.frete) { console.log(frete.frete[p]); }` it'll probably work, though may not be what you want.

Comment: ...also in the second to last screenshot. It shows `{"frete":{"0":{"peso":...` instead of `{"frete":[{"peso":...`

Comment: NOW, LIKE STOPED WORK. SIMPLY WORK. LOL

Comment: Maybe an older version of the data was cached. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Ty all guys and im sorry spend you time. I don't know why and how. Stoped work and work by him self. No code change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your PHP code. I can clearly see you JSON response

Your localhost PHP is seems to correct. Because "Working on localhost: http://prntscr.com/1mzwgc" is giving array against "frete" key in JSON, whereas in your production( http://prntscr.com/1mzw4w) the value against "frete" key is an Object. You can't use normal "for loop" against object other than "for-in loop"

Good luck

Answer (score -2):

I have simply taken your json result and stored in a variable called '**obj**' just taken `obj.yourkeyname.length`

```
var obj = {
"frete": [
    {
        "peso": "49300",
        "classificador": "Retira",
        "fk_frete": "15",
        "prazo": "Prazo de entrega até 2 dias",
        "fk_classificador": "445",
        "fator_cubagem": "4800",
        "peso_real": "1",
        "peso_cubado": "0",
        "fk_fre_peso": "0",
        "fk_fichario": "61440",
        "transportadora": "N",
        "preco_min": "0.00",
        "gratis": "0",
        "gratis_produtos": null,
        "exibir_estados": "0",
        "imagem": null,
        "preco": "0.001",
        "valor": "0.001"
    },
    {
        "peso": "49300",
        "classificador": "Moto boy",
        "fk_frete": "17",
        "prazo": "Prazo de entrega 1 dia",
        "fk_classificador": "151",
        "fator_cubagem": "4800",
        "peso_real": "1",
        "peso_cubado": "0",
        "fk_fre_peso": "0",
        "fk_fichario": "60646",
        "transportadora": "N",
        "preco_min": "0.00",
        "gratis": "0",
        "gratis_produtos": null,
        "exibir_estados": "0",
        "imagem": null,
        "preco": 0.0319249,
        "valor": 0.0319249
    },
    {
        "fk_frete": "27",
        "classificador": "Trans. Jamef",
        "prazo": "De 5 a 10 dias após o envio",
        "valor": 223.54,
        "transportadora": null,
        "fk_classificador": null
    },
    {
        "peso": 289260,
        "classificador": "Transportadora",
        "fk_frete": "28",
        "prazo": "Prazo de entrega 10 dias",
        "fk_classificador": "405",
        "fator_cubagem": "3333",
        "peso_real": "1",
        "peso_cubado": "1",
        "fk_fre_peso": "0",
        "fk_fichario": "56080",
        "transportadora": "Y",
        "preco_min": "0.00",
        "gratis": "0",
        "gratis_produtos": null,
        "exibir_estados": "0",
        "imagem": null,
        "preco": 0,
        "kiloadd": "1.000",
        "valor": 10.61
    }
],
"cidade": {
    "cidade": {
        "id": "6268",
        "nome": "Londrina"
    },
    "estado": {
        "id": "17",
        "nome": "Paraná",
        "uf": "PR"
    }
}
}


alert(obj.frete.length);
```

check the result it will be 4.